# Preston not working

Tags: fallout-4

Okay I am new to fallout 4 and when I did the mission where sturges he said go and help build sanctuary and talk to Preston but he won't respond and the first ever mission the Preston gives you has gone missing what do I do I don't what to restart ?

Answer (score 1):

The [wiki](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Sanctuary) mentions this being a bug that makes the mission impossible to complete, so unfortunately the only fix is **reloading the last save game** you made before starting that mission.

Two tips:

- in general: save your game regularly, for example before starting a new quest (this applies to all Fallout games: sometimes there are bugs and sometimes you want to try for a different outcome)
- apparently the chance of this bug popping up can be reduced by having all necessary materials before starting the quest.